# External hard drive 'complains' after computer switched off

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I have a Hitachi external Hard Drive, powered by 2 USB leads.  On my previous (XP) computer, I only needed to plug one of these into a USB socket; however on my new (Windows 8) computer I need to plug both in, otherwise the drive 'complains' with a kind of rhythmic squeaking noise.

When the computer is powered down, the hard drive again makes this noise instead of switching off.  It doesn't sound too healthy so I usually end up unplugging the hard drive until next time I boot up, although I don't always remember to do this, so it stays complaining all night.

Now the hard drive sometimes disconnects itself, so I have to unplug and reconnect it - which suggests to me that all this isn't helping.

Any advice, anyone?

Comment: The noise you’re hearing is your drive failing to power up because of a lack of power.

Answer (score 0):

The two usb plugs will probably be to do with the power requirements of the hard drive ([see the answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/193966/why-do-some-usb-cables-have-two-usb-connectors-at-the-end)). So you should definitely leave both plugged in.

As for the squeaking noise that probably isn't a good sign, does the squeaking noise sound [like this](http://youtu.be/8JIovrZ1hr8?t=58s) or like any of the noises on [this page](http://datacent.com/hard_drive_sounds.php)?

If it does, then I would back up your data ASAP as your hard drive might be failing and they can quickly go from being a little bit dodgy to completely dead.

It might also be worth trying the drives manufacturer's drive test software as it will sometimes pick on a failing drive. (sometimes included as an installer on the external hard drive or maybe [this one here](http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads#DFT)).
However drive self tests won't always tell you if a drive is failing so I would take any results with a pinch of salt.